# Magento Fails to Create Session and Shows Blank Screen After Login

Tags: admin, error

Hi Struggling with this one, done some reading and tried checking for blank spaces at the end of files. I actually removed a few but this didn't fix the issue even after clearing the cache.

The system is not creating any session data. There is nothing in var/session

Here is the error that magento is reporting:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:126:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php, line 1";i:1;s:1409:"#0 lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(106): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://planetto...', 302)
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(348): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://planetto...')
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(182): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->_redirect(Object(Varien_Simplexml_Element))
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6:"/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Look forward to getting any help.

Comment: check if the file `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php` has an empty space or any character before the php open tag `<?php`

Comment: My bet is on file permissions...

Comment: In addition to @Marius his answer, check out this post about whitespaces causing the error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/387136

Comment: I've checked for whitespaces and also ensured all file permissions are correct as per this page [link](https://support.terranetwork.net/web/knowledgebase/119/Resetting-File-Permissions-for-Magento.html) Still no joy :S

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:122:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php, line 1";
```

Simple solution: in Session.php there was a space before `<?php` opening tag  - just had to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

you can remove these three line from the following page.

Go to :

```
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\varien.php

// session cookie params
       $cookieParams = array(
           'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
           'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
           //'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
           //'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
           //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
       );
```

and then try to login it worked for me.

Comment: Hmm that didn't do the trick either :S

Comment: Improve PHP Memory Limit
If you can access php.ini OR use .htaccess in the root OR edit index.php add below line right after ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);

ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); try this

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Memory limit was set to 1024M, this had already crossed my mind. Also tried disabling extensions one by one. Still no joy. I also thought it might have been an issue with permissions on the var/session folder, so reset these and also still no joy :(

Comment: try this : https://lampjs.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/magento-admin-login-fail-session-problem/